# How to add multiple tracks from Finder to iTunes now playing list?

Tags: macos, itunes, finder

The new iTunes 11 finally contains a list with the current and to be played titles.

I'd like to add multiple files from the Finder to that list.

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: From the Finder? You only can add tracks which are already in iTunes.

Comment: How is there not an answer to this? iTunes is awful for playing files in a folder with different artists/album names. Windows has an explorer context menu option for this. And no, not everyone wants to have to create playlists.